# Null pointer exception on textview inside scrollview

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, textview

I'm trying to access a textview which is inside a scrollview from a fragment class, and I tried all suggestions I found from other relative questions, but I always get nullpointerexception at settext.

Here is my fragment class:

```
View view;
TextView links;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle         

 savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.help_4, null);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.svText);
    links = (TextView) sv.findViewById(R.id.tvHelpText4);
    links.setText("vblsarasdferadfkwersfadfwe");
    //links.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
/* Other code here */
}
```

and here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/help_settings"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:background="#0570A9"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"/>


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/svText">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/help_text4"
    android:id="@+id/tvHelpText4"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:autoLink="all"/>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE**
Thank you all for your help. The problem was with the resouces. I had another copy of the above xml on layout-hdpi folder. In some point I changed the id without to update the file. I deleted the file, but I forgot to clean the project. Now it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried `links = view.findViewById()` instead of `sv.findviewById`?

Comment: In onCreateView, I think you need container. try this. view = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

Comment: I already tried(I assume that your R.layout.fragment_home, is my R.layout.help_4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `textview` is a part of the same xml which contains the `scrollview`.

The hierarchy within an xml won't affect your findViewById(s)

```
 ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.svText);
    links = (TextView) sv.findViewById(R.id.tvHelpText4);
```

should be

```
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.svText);
    links = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvHelpText4);
```

and you will find the textview as a part of the same view.

***EDIT 1:***

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.svText);
    links = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvHelpText4);
    links.setText("vblsarasdferadfkwersfadfwe");
    //links.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
/* Other code here */
}
```

Also, clean-build once, i am curious why you aren't getting the NPE for scrollview and only for the textview in that case.

Just for that, see what happens if findViewById shifted to onCreateView like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle         

 savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.help_4, null);
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.svText);
    links = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvHelpText4);
    links.setText("vblsarasdferadfkwersfadfwe");
    return view;
}
```

Comment: I used view at first and get nullpointerexception. I tried with the first textview in xml and I it loads fine. So I thought that maybe the problem was that the textview I wanna use was inside a scrollview, and for this I tried the sv.findViewById(R.id.tvHelpText4);

Comment: what is the name of your xml? shift the findViewById code to inside onCreateView before returning the view.  But don't need to use scrollview to find the textview

Comment: layout's name: help_4

Comment: Also, add this as the first line inside onViewCreated: super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

Comment: If you mean like this: links = (TextView) this.view.findViewById(R.id.tvHelpText4);  I just now tried and I get the same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60385/discussion-between-dancer-69-and-user2450263).

Answer (score 2):

Replace sv with view

```
 ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.svText);
links = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvHelpText4);
links.setText("vblsarasdferadfkwersfadfwe");
```

Answer (score 2):

change  `links = (TextView) sv.findViewById(R.id.tvHelpText4)`

to

```
links = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvHelpText4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are Creating Textview under ScrollView but Your havein View i.e.

so repleace the line:

```
links = (TextView) sv.findViewById(R.id.tvHelpText4);
```

via

```
links = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvHelpText4);
```